# Phone pattern for <input type="tel"> in HTML

Tags: html, forms

So I tried to run the following code to practice using HTML forms and the telephone no. part is giving a problem. When I type any telephone number which according to me should satisfy the requirements, it says "Please match the requested format". I believe the requirements ask for a number with ten digits each of which are from 1 to 9. Did I write my requirements wrong? Help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<title>
Forms in HTML5 :)
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form align="center">Name:<input type="text" autocomplete><br><br>
Email:<input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
Date of Inception:<input type="time" name="usr_time"><br><br>
Number of years completed(between 1 and 100):<input type="number" min="1" max="100"><br><br>
Office phone number: <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{10}'' required><br><br>
Add your homepage:
<input type="url" name="homepage"><br><br>
<input type="image" src="E:/HTML1/SUBMIT-BUTTON.png" height="60" width="180" alt="click here to submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean from 0 to 9?

Comment: You have mismatched quotes in the sample you provided: `pattern="[0-9]{10}''`

Comment: When you fix your quotes it will work as you expect. Matching 10 numbers from 0 to 9.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys its working now. Made a very silly mistake it seems :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wrote `''` instead of `"` in `pattern="[0-9]{10}"`

this code works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<title>
Forms in HTML5 :)
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form align="center">Name:<input type="text" autocomplete><br><br>
Email:<input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
Date of Inception:<input type="time" name="usr_time"><br><br>
Number of years completed(between 1 and 100):<input type="number" min="1" 
max="100"><br><br>
Office phone number: <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]. 
{10}" required><br><br>
Add your homepage:
<input type="url" name="homepage"><br><br>
<input type="image" src="E:/HTML1/SUBMIT-BUTTON.png" height="60" width="180" 
alt="click here to submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working now. Thanks a lot. Somehow I made a very silly mistake even after rechecking that part of the code multiple times. Weird.